# PHP - preg split all sentences except last line

Tags: php, regex

I have a txt file with the below text and want to display it on a page. Each sentence have been placed in an array and everything seems to be working. I'm spliting the sentences by space but since the last row somethings includes messages with line breaks and spaces it also gets splited and the rest of the message will be added in separeted rows. How can I except the last column to not split for space and/or line-break and just let them be on the same row?

```
ADDRESS TIME     DATE     MODE   TYPE    BITRATE MESSAGE
199999  00:05:39 25-05-05 MODE-1 NUMERIC 100     message goes here
199999  00:05:39 25-05-05 MODE-1 NUMERIC 100     message goes here
199999  00:05:39 25-05-05 MODE-1 NUMERIC 100     message goes here
                                                 and here as well!
```

this is how it looks on my page

```
199999  00:05:39  25-05-05  MODE-1  NUMERIC  100      message goes here
199999  00:05:39  25-05-05  MODE-1  NUMERIC  100      message goes here
199999  00:05:39  25-05-05  MODE-1  NUMERIC  100      message goes here
        and       here      as      well!
```

this is what i'm using, which I guess is incorrect.

```
  $file_handle = fopen("lib/today.txt", "r");

      echo "<table>";
           while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
      $line_of_text = utf8_encode(fgets($file_handle));
      $parts = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$line_of_text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
      echo
      "<tr>
      <td>" . $parts[0] . "</td>
      <td>" . $parts[1] . "</td>
      <td>" . $parts[2] . "</td>
      <td>" . $parts[3] . "</td>
      <td>" . $parts[4] . "</td>
      <td>" . $parts[5] . "</td>
      <td>" . $parts[6] . "</td>
      </tr>";

      }
      echo "</table>";

      fclose($file_handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the $parts array to match the minumun expected length (7+)

```
$parts = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$line_of_text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
if (count($parts)>=7){
   // $parts content is fine
}
```

Also, you can pre-check the line using a more specific regular expression like this example (this one is only to check if the line starts with numbers, you can add additional rules depending on the line format):

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+ /',$line_of_text)){
  // line is ok
  $parts = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$line_of_text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

The problem with separating into words is: the final message will be separated into parts. You can re-join those parts from the array (from index 6):

```
$message=implode(" ",array_slice($parts,6));
```

EDIT:
In your code example, replace `$parts[6]` with the result of `$message`:

```
$file_handle = fopen("lib/today.txt", "r");
echo "<table>";
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
 $line_of_text = utf8_encode(fgets($file_handle));
 $parts = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$line_of_text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
 if (count($parts)>=7){
  echo
  "<tr>
  <td>" . $parts[0] . "</td>
  <td>" . $parts[1] . "</td>
  <td>" . $parts[2] . "</td>
  <td>" . $parts[3] . "</td>
  <td>" . $parts[4] . "</td>
  <td>" . $parts[5] . "</td>
  <td>" . implode(" ",array_slice($parts,6)) . "</td>
  </tr>";
 }
}
echo "</table>";
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: alright thanks, i edited my post to include all of my code. I tried with the pre-check code but the last parts of the messages is still on separated rows. could you please include where in my code I should place it?

Comment: @relova I've added an example based on your code.

Comment: thank you so much, it works! But for some reason, every line that ends with an hyphen will line-break the row? So it only affects $parts[2] and $parts[3]. Is that because the preg_split?

Comment: edit: the hyphen thing was css related.. it's all good now!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to output it formatted with spacing for HTML then you can do:

```
echo nl2br(str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', htmlentities(preg_replace('/^ADDRESS.*MESSAGE[\r\n]*/','',$str))));
```

If you plan to enclose it in `<pre></pre>` then this would work:

```
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities(preg_replace('/^ADDRESS.*MESSAGE[\r\n]*/','',$str)).'</pre>';
```